# Grid editing in Kendo

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I hava a kendo grid which is set to be editable. It is working fine. all I need is to show a empty row in my grid regardless of any items present or not. This editable row should always come. for that I have searched various questions here also but none of them is working except the below:

```
 $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: TableDataSource,
            autoBind: true,
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: {
                allowUnsort: false
            },
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                buttonCount: 5,
                pageSizes: 5
            },
            noRecords: {
                template: "No records found."
            },
            dataBound : function () {
                var firstItem = this.dataSource.view()[0];
                if (firstItem.isNew() == false) {
                   firstItem.isNew();
                    this.addRow();
                }
            },
   editable: true,
```

But here the problem is that it only shows a new row if grid have atleast one record coming from database . If Grid is empty, it is not adding a row in grid.

If I remove if condition , then the grid goes into infinite loop and crashes the browser.

I also tried this in document.ready but there is no success. Grid just don't respond

```
 $(function(){
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
       grid.dataSource.insert( {} );//Not working
       grid.addRow(); // Not working  

    });
```

Comment: The `dataBound` function is called when just that happens, row's get dataBound...when you have no records, rows don't get dataBound. You're going to need use a different function. Perhaps the `dataBinding` event would be best. Check out all the events here http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid

Comment: Its not working. The databinding event works after databound. It is also not helping me. Any other idea?

Comment: Does this help? http://dojo.telerik.com/ubaca

Comment: This is Superb. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But what this line does firstItem.isNew()